# a topological property

Tags: general-topology

every closed set is not the closure of some open set.

Under what conditions will a closed set be equal to the closure of an open set?I mean, what do we need to make a closed set equal to the closure of an open set?

Comment: "not every closed set..."

Comment: When it is regular closed.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, not every closed set is the closure of an open set. Such closed sets are called *regular closed* and are characterised by the equation $$A= \overline{\operatorname{int}(A)}$$

In a regular space all closed sets are the intersection of a family of regular closed sets (exercise). The dual notion is being regular open, i. e. the interior of a closed set.